Uninstalled and Re-Installed Vault. But still says “error: Vault is already initialized”
I uninstalled vault :
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# helm uninstall -n $VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE $VAULT_HELM_RELEASE_NAME hashicorp/vault
release "vault" uninstalled

And re-installed it via helm:
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# helm install -n $VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE $VAULT_HELM_RELEASE_NAME hashicorp/vault -f ${WORKDIR}/overrides.yaml
NAME: vault
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Sep  9 15:08:38 2024
NAMESPACE: vault
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
Thank you for installing HashiCorp Vault!

root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# kubectl -n $VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
vault-0                                 0/1     Running   0          57s
vault-1                                 0/1     Running   0          57s
vault-2                                 0/1     Running   0          57s
vault-agent-injector-588bdf8d9d-mkl99   1/1     Running   0          57s

Tried to re-initialize it but got "error: Vault is already initialized"
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# kubectl exec -n $VAULT_K8S_NAMESPACE vault-0 -- vault operator init \
>     -key-shares=3 \
>     -key-threshold=3 \
>     -format=json > ${WORKDIR}/cluster-keys.json
Error initializing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init
Code: 400. Errors:

* Vault is already initialized
command terminated with exit code 2

What else do I have to do, apart from uninstall vault, and remove /tmp/vault folder, in order to be able to initialize it again?

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/platform/k8s/helm

Security Warning: By default, the chart runs in standalone mode. This mode uses a single Vault server with a file storage backend. This is a less secure and less resilient installation that is NOT appropriate for a production setup. It is highly recommended to use a properly secured Kubernetes cluster, learn the available configuration options, and read the production deployment checklist.

Perhaps the file storage backend wasn't removed when you uninstalled the helm chart. If you're unsure, post your ${WORKDIR}/overrides.yaml contents in your question.

Hi @mfinni ! Thanks for helping. I solved deleting all api-resources related with vault. I guess what was blocking was the bound pvc

SOLVED by deleting all api-resources related with vault
